# Can you target the logs from an S3 bucket to an S3 bucket in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I have an S3 bucket in account A that I'd like to turn logging on for I have to select a bucket for the logs to be written to. Is it possible to set permissions such that I can select a bucket in account B for these logs to be written to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question better suited to be asked of the vendor.

Comment: @Wesley you don't think that s3 is of sufficient general interest that it is in serverfault's interest to have answers to specific use cases answered on serverfault?

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you could easily create a Lambda function that is triggered upon S3 object creation, that copies files to the other S3 bucket.